# Why does my app crash invoking "setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)"

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar, android-architecture-navigation

I am getting an error message in the LogCat window of Android Studio;

```
Process: com.riverstonetech.gositeuk, PID: 27370
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.riverstonetech.gositeuk/com.riverstonetech.gositeuk.CountriesActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at androidx.navigation.ui.ActionBarOnDestinationChangedListener.setTitle(ActionBarOnDestinationChangedListener.java:48)
        at androidx.navigation.ui.AbstractAppBarOnDestinationChangedListener.onDestinationChanged(AbstractAppBarOnDestinationChangedListener.java:100)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(NavController.java:218)
        at androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(NavigationUI.java:220)
        at androidx.navigation.ui.ActivityKt.setupActionBarWithNavController(Activity.kt:74)
        at com.riverstonetech.gositeuk.CountriesActivity.onCreate(CountriesActivity.kt:31)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

when I run my app containing the following code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_countries)

    val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.

    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.englandFragment, R.id.scotlandFragment, R.id.walesFragment, R.id.nirelandFragment
        )
    )

    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

}
```

The app crashes when it reaches the line;

```
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

Comment: Have you checked the logcat for the exception  stack trace?

Comment: What should I be looking for in the exception stack trace?

Comment: The cause of the crash, mostly. If you can't really parse it, then it should be appended to the question so that we can see it. In this case, the crash seems internal to the navigation helper calls, so I'd definitely be curious to see where they are actually calling `actionBar.setTitle`.

Comment: Exception stack trace added

Answer (score 15):

Sounds like you have a theme set for your Activity that has `.NoActionBar`.

A safer solution to using the action bar is to use a `Toolbar` as part of your layout, then use 
`setupWithNavController(Toolbar toolbar, NavController navController, AppBarConfiguration configuration)`

If you do want to use an action bar, then your Activity needs a theme that provides an ActionBar. Check your AndroidManifest.xml and styles.xml.

Comment: I have no idea. Can you direct me to an online resource where I can learn about action bars and themes?

Comment: The official docs were outdated (referencing Holo and stuff), check this article: https://antonioleiva.com/material-design-everywhere/

Comment: Thanks but I think I need even more basic information on navigation in Android as I am just learning about Android app building.

Comment: Ah, Jetpack Navigation is fairly new (and that's what you seem to be using), so you might want to look at https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started as I personally don't use it (I use the underlying mechanisms instead as I didn't need a graphic editor). I hope the docs describe it well, though.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to use the action bar. Remove the below code

```
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

Or change the NoActionBar to DarkActionBar or any others.

Answer (score 4):

The method `setupActionBarWithNavController()` assumes you have an `ActionBar`.
In you code you aren't calling `setSupportActionBar()` and if you are using `.NoActionBar` theme, you don't have an `ActionBar`.

Just use a `Toolbar` in your layout and use:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  //..
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_countries)
  val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
  setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
  //...
  setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
  //..
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and solved the problem. I hope this helps.
The problem was I did not add dependencies for fragment library.

1. Add fragment dependencies on app level build.gradle.
   implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.4'
   implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.4'
2. Clean build (Build -> Clean Project)
3. Invalidate Caches and Restart (if developer PC OS is Windows)
4. Reboot PC (I do not know why. but if I don't reboot PC, the problem occurs again. )
5. After reboot, build and run the app again.

Answer (score 2):

**ANDROID JAVA**

**Option 1:**
Change Activity AppTheme on Manifest or add new style on styles.xml and apply tothe activity

**Option 2:**
Add Action Bar to Layout file like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

On Activity after setContentView() add this:

```
 Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Enjoy